# Find all CSS files on website using PHP

Tags: php, css, web-crawler

As the title suggest i am trying to find all CSS files on a website (for later use i will find all image urls in each of the CSS files on the server).

Now ive tried the following:

```
    $url_to_test = $_GET['url'];
$file = file_get_contents($url_to_test);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($file);
$domcss = $doc->getElementsByTagName('css');
```

However the array domcss turned out empty (for a site i know has alot of css files).

So my question is how do i find all css files loaded on a given page?

Comment: The html tag for css ist `link`

Comment: Uhm, im not familiar with things like that, but the "TagName" is not css. You need <link rel="stylesheet" href="your/css/file">, so ofc you get an enmty array.

Comment: May I ask what your use case is? It sounds like there may be a simpler solution to the problem.

Comment: I have a javascript that calls a function that quickly will get all images of the site and returns it as a json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should check for `link` not `css`, change:

```
$domcss = $doc->getElementsByTagName('css');
```

to

```
$domcss = $doc->getElementsByTagName('link');
foreach($domcss as $links) {
    if( strtolower($links->getAttribute('rel')) == "stylesheet" ) {
       echo "This is:". $links->getAttribute('href') ."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! how will i check that the link is of type css?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/<link rel="stylesheet" href="(.*?)" type="text\/css">/',$data,$output_array);
```

Comment: what is data and what is output?

Comment: data is your data you grabbed, with curl or any other way. And output is an array of css files..

Comment: Okay. The following returns an empty array:     $file = file_get_contents('http://www.as.com/');
    preg_match('/<link rel="stylesheet" href="(.*?)" type="text\/css">/', $file, $matches);

Comment: Okay apprently it cant type http but it is http as.com

Comment: try to grab data with curl

Comment: This will only work when the link element looks exactly like this. Parsing HTML with regular expressions is usually futile.